# Ajax works only debug mode

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Here is a MyLinkButton

```
<a id="btnUpdateActivityD"  style="margin: 10px 5px;" class="btn blue-soft pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;Ok
</a>
```

then those are Ajax Codes

```
  $("#btnUpdateActivityD").on('click', function () {
         var activity = new ActivityObject(parseInt(activityId), $("#txtActivityNameD").val(), $("#txtActivityCodeD").val(), startDate, endDate, true, parseInt($("#ddlActivityTypeD").val()), parseInt($("#ddlActivityCompD").val()), parseInt($("#ddlActivityTrainerD").val()), parseInt($("#ddlActivityPlaceD").val()), $("#txtActivityDescD").val(), parseInt(activityTotalPerson), 1);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ActivityDetail.aspx/UpdateActivity",
                data: "{act:" + JSON.stringify(activity) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                },
                error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    debugger;
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(activityX));
                    //console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                },

            });

            window.parent.closeActivityDetailModal();
            window.parent.RefreshActivityList();
            window.parent.toastrNotification("success");


        });
```

Hi everyone; ajax post only can work debug mode. If project is run normally, ajax post doesn't work, catch the error line and get message like result.responseText = ""  Can you help me? I could research and review again and again my documents, stacoverflow pages and code blocks but i didnt solve.

Comment: check jquery library exist in your source code.

Comment: look your code maybe under the method success.

Comment: i checked before and code works correctly in debug so code not wrong but normal mode drop error

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 $("#btnUpdateActivityD").on('click', function () {
         var activity = new ActivityObject(parseInt(activityId), $("#txtActivityNameD").val(), $("#txtActivityCodeD").val(), startDate, endDate, true, parseInt($("#ddlActivityTypeD").val()), parseInt($("#ddlActivityCompD").val()), parseInt($("#ddlActivityTrainerD").val()), parseInt($("#ddlActivityPlaceD").val()), $("#txtActivityDescD").val(), parseInt(activityTotalPerson), 1);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ActivityDetail.aspx/UpdateActivity",
                data: "{act:" + JSON.stringify(activity) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (result) {
                     window.parent.closeActivityDetailModal();
            window.parent.RefreshActivityList();
            window.parent.toastrNotification("success");

                },
                error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    debugger;
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(activityX));
                    //console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                },

            });



        });
```

Because you are using ajax, the callback and the actions must be under success, or error methods

Comment: put it into the method error, could be a query with bad response